# SQL Count non existing item

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count, left-join

I have table Groups,

```
ID  NUMBER
STATUS  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
```

I am able to count the number of status as following.

```
select g.status, count(*) from groups g group by g.status;

STATUS                 COUNT(*)
-------------------- ----------
OK                            2 
NOK                           1
```

I have another status ,say PENDING, REJECTED. But there is no item exists in table, but I want them to be shown with zero count as following.

```
STATUS                 COUNT(*)
-------------------- ----------
OK                            2 
NOK                           1 
PENDING                       0 
REJECTED                      0
```

What will be the SQL statement to make it possible?

Comment: Are all the different Status in another table ?

Comment: no there is not Status table,

Comment: You cannot show information, that doesn't exist.

Comment: The query specified by you will do it by default. Have you tried inserting those status in your table ? If it is showing like NULL then try with ISNULL(COL,REPLACE_VALUE)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT A.status, COUNT(DISTINCT G.ID) statusCnt
FROM (SELECT 'OK' status FROM DUAL
      UNION 
      SELECT 'NOK' status FROM DUAL
      UNION 
      SELECT 'PENDING' status FROM DUAL
      UNION 
      SELECT 'REJECTED' status FROM DUAL
     ) AS A 
LEFT JOIN groups G ON A.status = G.STATUS 
GROUP BY A.status;
```

Comment: having following error:  Error starting at line 15 in command:
SELECT A.statusName, COUNT(DISTINCT G.ID) statusCnt FROM 
  (SELECT 'OK' status
      UNION 
      SELECT 'NOK' status
      UNION 
      SELECT 'PENDING' status
      UNION 
      SELECT 'REJECTED' status
    ) AS A 
LEFT JOIN groups G ON A.status = G.STATUS 
GROUP BY A.status
Error at Command Line:17 Column:7
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @mmc18 You had changed the column alias in inner query from `statusName` to `status` but you had not changed column name in first line add `SELECT A.status,` instead of `SELECT A.statusName,`

Comment: @mmc18 I had changed column alias in my answer. Check the updated answer

Comment: having same error, I think it isnot about alians:   Error starting at line 16 in command:
SELECT A.status, COUNT(DISTINCT G.ID) statusCnt
FROM (SELECT 'OK' status
      UNION 
      SELECT 'NOK' status
      UNION 
      SELECT 'PENDING' status
      UNION 
      SELECT 'REJECTED' status
     ) AS A 
LEFT JOIN groups G ON A.status = G.STATUS 
GROUP BY A.status
Error at Command Line:18 Column:7
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @mmc18 Which database server you are using?

Comment: my DB servers are Oracle 11g and PostgreSQL

Comment: @mmc18 In oracle you can't write select query as `SELECT 'OK' status`. You have to use `DUAL` table to do that. So the query is `SELECT 'OK' status FROM DUAL` etc...

Comment: Error starting at line 15 in command:
SELECT A.status, COUNT(DISTINCT G.ID) statusCnt
FROM (SELECT 'OK' status FROM DUAL
      UNION 
      SELECT 'NOK' status FROM DUAL
      UNION 
      SELECT 'PENDING' status FROM DUAL
      UNION 
      SELECT 'REJECTED' status FROM DUAL
     ) AS A 
LEFT JOIN groups G ON A.status = G.STATUS 
GROUP BY A.status
Error at Command Line:23 Column:8
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: you should remove "AS"

Answer (score 2):

If exists a table with list of states you can write your query in this way:

I suppose your state registry has called STATES

```
SELECT
    states.status,
    (select count(*) from groups g where g.status = states.status)
FROM states
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT
    s.status, count(*)
FROM states s
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups g
    ON s.status = g.status
GROUP BY s.status
```

Otherwise you can't obtain this information

**EDIT** (AFTER COMMENT)

Please create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE states
(id int,
status varchar(20))
```

In your tables GROUPS replace status field with fk to states table

Comment: I would advise not to use a subselect, but a join. If your table gets large, the performance of the subselect will decrease dramatically.

Comment: @Seb: If you use a LEFT OUTER JOIN you must use GROUP BY (a little heavy too)

Comment: If you have an index on the group.status field that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Seb: The same thing about subquery, if you've indexed status field

Comment: @Seb: I've added the version with left outer join to complete my answer ;)

Comment: What if I want to add an other group column in addition to group name and status count. What needs to change SQL statement ?

Answer (score 1):

I think a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the results would be a simple and fast solution.

Like other answers, assuming you have a "states" table lists the desired "states", you can join the "status" table with the "group by" results and fill NULL values as 0.

```
SELECT s.status,COALESCE(gs.numGroups,0)
FROM states AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT status,count(*) AS numGroups FROM groups AS g GROUP BY status) AS gs
  ON gs.status=states.status
```

And the results would look like this (tested in SQLite):

```
status            numGroups
---------------------------
OK                2
NOK               1
PENDING           0
REJECTED          0
```

Note that the COALESCE function maybe called differently in other databases, e.g. IFNULL in SQLite, or ISNULL in SQL server

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select g.status, ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) from groups g group by g.status;
```

Comment: GROUP By an inexisting value won't make it magically appear, even with ISNULL