# SQL Count non existing item with two column

Tags: sql

I have asked similar question [SQL Count non existing item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655636/sql-count-non-existing-item/20656280#20656280).
But I need another point of view. Here is my different version of question.

I have table Groups,

```
ID  NUMBER
STATUS  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
OWNER  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
```

I am able to count the number of status as following. (taking account owner tuple as well)

```
 select g.owner, g.status, count(*) countRS from groups g group by g.owner, g.status order by g.owner ;  

OWNER                STATUS                  COUNTRS
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
JOHN                 NOK                           1 
JOHN                 OK                            2 
MARK                 OK                            1
```

I have another status ,say PENDING, REJECTED. But there is no item exists in table, but I want them to be shown with zero count as following.

```
OWNER                STATUS                  COUNTRS
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
JOHN                 NOK                           1 
JOHN                 OK                            2 
JOHN                 PENDING                       0 
JOHN                 REJECTED                      0 
MARK                 OK                            1 
MARK                 NOK                           0
MARK                 PENDING                       0 
MARK                 REJECTED                      0
```

Comment: Apply the same logic applied in the other question, where you have got the correct answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Count non existing item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655636/sql-count-non-existing-item)

Comment: And the same question applies: Do you have a table containing all statusses or are they just in your head?

Comment: No there is not a table having status values.

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli. It is not dublicate since as I have stated that this question is another version of that question which is asked by myself as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query below will get the cartesian product of unique owner on table `group` to the number of records of status. The result rows will then be joined on table `groups` so we can be able to count the number of status per owner.

```
SELECT  a.owner, b.status,
        COUNT(g.status) TotalCount
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT OWNER FROM groups) a
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT  'NOK' `status` UNION ALL
            SELECT  'OK' `status` UNION ALL
            SELECT  'PENDING' `status` UNION ALL
            SELECT  'REJECTED' `status` 
        ) b
        LEFT JOIN groups g
            ON  a.owner = g.owner
                AND b.status = g.status
GROUP   BY a.owner, b.status
ORDER   BY a.owner, b.status
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f3876/2)

Comment: Having following error.Error at Command Line:46 Column:27
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
      delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language Reference Manual.
*Action:

Answer (score 0):

Add a "Status" table to your DB. Change "Status" field in "Groups" table to "StatusId", which should link to that new table. Then in your select you can right join "Status" table, and this will give rows in query result for missing status too.